# Joomla - redirect using article alias name?

Tags: joomla3.0

I am new to joomla,

I am working in redirection based on article alias name, is it possible without any component

For eg:, www.domain.com/sitename/category/article-alias

This s not working, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think using .htaccess is the best way for this.   Here's how:

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

You need to make sure your htaccess.txt file is renamed as .htaccess first or it won't work.  You should also check that your site works after renaming it as sometimes it may require a bit of configuration.